# Не работает serialize and unserialize

Tags: ubuntu, serialize, unserialize, php, apache2

Не создаётся файл при сериализации и, соответсвенно, невозможно добавить в него данные и тем более открыть. Сам apache2 установлен на ubuntu, а корневая папка сервера находится в `var/www/html`.

Вот код:

class.php

```
<?php

    class cls{

        public $var;

        public function __construct($var){

            $this->var=$var;

        }

    }

?>
```

index.php

```
<?php

            require_once("class.php");

            $obj=new cls(99);

            $text=serialize($obj);

            $fd=fopen("text.txt", "w");

            if(!$fd) exit("error");

            fwrite($fd, $text);

            fclose($fd);

            echo $obj->var;

        ?>
```

unserialize.php

```
<?php

    require_once("class.php");

    $fd=fopen("text.txt", "r");

    if(!$fd) exit("error");

    $text=unserialize($text);

    echo "<pre>";

    print_r($obj);

    echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Думал, что мне не хватает прав на создание файла, запустил редактор через терминал с правами супер пользователя, но один фиг, то же самое, выдаёт, что невозможно открыть файл.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать file_put_contents() и file_get_contents()